# MySQL socket timeout behaviour on @Transactional

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot (2.3.4.RELEASE) with MySQL (8.0.21).

My database config in spring boot is

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?connectTimeout=2000&socketTimeout=10000&autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=toor
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1 from dual where @@innodb_read_only = 0
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

###### MySQL Connector

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
```

###### Dbcp2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

###### I had tested the following code template and found this weird behaviour

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional
public void f1() {
  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT sleep(12)", new HashMap<>(), Integer.class);
}
```

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional
public void f2() {
  Thread.sleep(12000);
  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT count(*) from my_table", new HashMap<>(), Integer.class);
}
```

###### The first function is giving this error:

```
11:10:07.862 [qtp262911569-27] ERROR o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT sleep(12)]; Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 10,013 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 10,013 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.MySQL.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 10,013 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 10,013 milliseconds ago.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:100)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:236)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:245)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:261)
```

###### While the second one works properly.

I know this has something to do with the socket timeout that is being set in the MySQL URL to 10 sec, in the config I mentioned above. But not sure what is happening behind the scenes. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here?

Comment: The first function is weird. You have it marked Transactional, yet there is no transaction happening. You just have a "SELECT sleep(12)"

Comment: @KausUntwale Sufficient for a minimal working code example, I guess - even if semantics are pointless. But you are right - behaviour of a true transaction with sleep(12) in-between would be interesting.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this doesn't just make sense... If you set a timeout to 10 seconds (socket timeout) but submit an operation that takes 12 seconds then of course the operation would abort at roughly 10 seconds with a disconnect socket failure every time. Why would it ever work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with changes in the application.properties as:-

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

each minute (60000 millis) test connection executing the query “SELECT 1” will be performed. In this way we can keep alive the database connection, periodically performing a validation query, and avoid to reach the MySQL’s wait_timeout.